# Windows 10 Universal App - Package doesn't work normally as debug mode

Tags: networking, uwp

```
public async Task<List<Tip>> GetTips()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://APIURL ");
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    WebResponse res = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
    string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    List<Tip> tips = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tip>>(result);
    return tips;
}
```

I am working on a project which need to consume an enterprise Web API(Https) and display the data on Win 10 live tile, it’s an UWP application.

But I found it only works when I ran it in IDE(Visual Studio 2015 debug mode) .
When I created a package for this app and run it by powershell for installation, request.GetResponseAsync method throws exception “The login request was denied”.

I tried to check Enterprise Authentication and Private Networks(Client & Server) options in Package.appxmanifest. But there was no effect.

Any idea how to make it work normally? Thanks.

Comment: Did you test your app in the release mode before you package your app?

Comment: Yes, I tested my app in release mode and it worked well.

Comment: @Criss 1. What's the version of your visual studio? 2. Because this is 502 Proxy Error(The login request was denied), so what's the network status for the device which can encounter this issue? What about install the package in your dev machine and check the result?